# Pauli-Exclusion Principle, Why not a force?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, pauli-exclusion-principle

I understand the mechanics of the Pauli-Exclusion principle and how it is a common sense idea that a fermion can not occupy the same coordinates, quantum state, as another one.

---

Why is the Pauli-Exclusion principle not considered a force rather than just a principle?

Comment: can you please send me the URL of that question because I looked for it and I can't find it. I would very much appreciate it.